# What is the SpecialVersion in a NuGet package version?

Tags: c#, version, nuget, nuget-package

When looking over the source code of `NuGet.Core`, I noticed that `SemanticVersion` has a constructor `public SemanticVersion(Version version, string specialVersion)`...

What exactly is this specialVersion? Can anyone give an example of how it looks on a real NuGet package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special version is used with pre-release NuGet packages where part of the version number includes an arbitrary string.

So if you have a pre-release package with the version:

```
   1.1.2-beta1
```

The special version will be **beta1**.